# Add a number through out a loop

Tags: ruby

I want to iterate 14 times, and add 2.50 to `x` each time, so the variables change as:

```
i = 0, x = 5.5
i = 1, x = 8
i = 2, x = 10.5
i = 3, x = 13
...
```

I did:

```
base_times = 14
base_times.times do |i|
  x = 3
  x = x + 2.50
  puts "#{x}"
end
```

Comment: Be careful with indentation.  Any modern text/programmer's editor will help you out, and it's important--not for the computer, but for human readers.

Comment: `(1..14).map { |i| (i * 2.50) + 3 }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of variable scope, you should move x definition out:

```
base_times=14
x=3
base_times.times do |i|
    x += 2.50
    puts "#{x}"
end
```

Also there's syntactic sugar for `x = x +`, `+=`.

Comment: @NicolásPojmaevich  Sure thing :)

Comment: @NicolásPojmaevich accept the answer if he answers your question. There is a tic below downvote button which you need to click, it would turn out to be green immediately after your click.

Comment: The block variable `i` is not used so there is no reason to include it. `puts "#{x}"` can be simplified to `puts x`. I suggest you simplify to `base_times.times { puts x += 2.50 }`,

Answer (score 0):

```
start      = 3
increment  = 2.5
base_times = 6

enum = (start+increment).step(by: increment)
base_times.times { puts enum.next }
```

prints

```
3.0
5.5
8.0
10.5
13.0
15.5
```

See [Numeric#step](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Numeric.html#method-i-step).